# Ruby on Rails 4: Can't edit posts or comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is how my app is setup.

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :forums
end

#app/models/forum.rb
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :posts
end


#app/models/post.rb
class post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :forum
    has_many :comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
end
```

I'm having issues with my comment records. I can display them and create them, but can't edit/delete them as I can't figure out which link to set.

Here's my config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_up => 'register', :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}

  resources :categories
  resources :forums do
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
  root 'categories#index'
end
```

Here is my comments controller.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @comment.save

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to [@forum, @post]
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @forum = Forum.find(params(:forum_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

    if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:foumd_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

_comments.html.haml

```
.comment.clearfix
    .content
        %p.comment_content= comment.comment
        %p.comment_author= comment.user.email
    .buttons
        = link_to "Edit", edit_forum_post_comment_path[@forum, @post]
```

I'm also having issues with editing my posts, I can create them no problem but can't edit them...

Posts controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def create
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to [@forum, @post]
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to [@forum, @post]
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

Logs

```
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.073062 #18541]  INFO -- : Started GET "/forums/1/posts/1/" for 24.220.125.144 at 2015-11-15 16:10:25 -0600
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.122253 #18541]  INFO -- : Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.122482 #18541]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"forum_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
D, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.148865 #18541] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mPost Load (0.5ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts$
D, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.185328 #18541] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.4ms)^[[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`post_id$
D, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.187051 #18541] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mComment Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHER$
D, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.210686 #18541] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mUser Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id$
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.232349 #18541]  INFO -- :   Rendered comments/_comment.html.haml (35.4ms)
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.232600 #18541]  INFO -- :   Rendered posts/show.html.haml within layouts/application (69.7ms)
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.233044 #18541]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 110ms (ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)
F, [2015-11-15T16:10:25.235567 #18541] FATAL -- :
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :forum_id=>"1", :id=>"1"} missing required key$
    3:          %p.comment_content= comment.comment
    4:          %p.comment_author= comment.user.email
    5:  .buttons
    6:          = link_to "Edit", edit_forum_post_comment_path[@forum, @post]
  app/views/comments/_comment.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_comments__comment_html_haml___1270861655862681835_22931440'
  app/views/posts/show.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_haml__2051422644921131492_20982460'
```

```
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.372822 #18541]  INFO -- : Started GET "/forums/1/posts/1/edit" for 24.220.125.144 at 2015-11-15 16:10:28 -0600
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.375577 #18541]  INFO -- : Processing by PostsController#edit as HTML
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.375656 #18541]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"forum_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
D, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.377175 #18541] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mPost Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts$
D, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.379458 #18541] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mUser Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id$
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.403726 #18541]  INFO -- :   Rendered posts/_form.html.haml (20.6ms)
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.403924 #18541]  INFO -- :   Rendered posts/edit.html.haml within layouts/application (22.8ms)
I, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.404187 #18541]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
F, [2015-11-15T16:10:28.405890 #18541] FATAL -- :
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `post_path' for #:0x00000003e04f18>):
    1: = simple_form_for [@forum,@post] do |f|
    2:  = f.input :title
    3:  = f.input :content
    4:  = f.submit
  app/views/posts/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_haml__3317057176452412006_32596640'
  app/views/posts/edit.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_posts_edit_html_haml__3955498671314368903_32545500'
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you might have better luck getting an answer if you clean up the question. In its current form, less people are going to make the effort to read it.

Comment: starting with posting the full error (your error blocks are cut off to the right) and then the views that the errors come from, and removing all of the other unrelated code, would be a great start at cleaning it up.

Answer (score 0):

The error is as follows:

> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :forum_id=>"1", :id=>"1"} missing required key$
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `post_path' for #:0x00000003e04f18>):

When asking questions / debugging in general, you need to start with the error / problem.

You've put up so much code most people will turn their noses up.

--

The error suggests a problem with your **routes**:

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :categories
  resources :forums do
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
  root 'categories#index'
end
```

The issue appears to be the way you're nesting your `forms` / `posts` / `comments`:

The first error is because you've not passed the `post_id`:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Comment", edit_forum_post_comment_path(@forum, @post, @comment) %>
```

The second error is because (I think) you've called your path without having the `@forum` variable populated. You should make sure that `@forum` is populated as follows:

```
@forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id]
@post = Post.new
```

Alternatively, you could build the `post` object on the `@forum` object, like so:

```
@forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id]
@post = @forum.posts.build
```

This should allow you to call `<%= form_for @post do |f| %>`

---

As a secondary to this, you need to look up the [`limits to nesting`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting), as it deals directly with your problem:

> *Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.*

Whilst I'd have to spend some time thinking about the best way to fix your issue, I'd do something like the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :forums do 
   resources :posts, :comments
end
```

This will set the `comments` directly below the `forums` resource, allowing you to skip having to associate a `forum` and `post` each time you want to do anything with them...

```
<%= link_to "Edit Comment", edit_forums_comments_path(@forum, @comment) %>
```